# Does ROW_NUMBER() support OVER(ORDER BY 1)?

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

Below 2 statments giving 2 different results

```
SELECT t.EID,t.name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) AS ROW_NUM
  FROM ESWAR t
;
```

```
EID  NAME   ROW_NUM
2    Ram       1
1    Siva      2
3    Deva      3
```

```sql
SELECT t.EID, t.name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.EID) AS ROW_NUM
  FROM ESWAR t
;
```

```
EID NAME    ROW_NUM
1   Siva       1
2   Ram    2
3   Deva       3
```

Comment: Because Order by is different in both queries. The first query has `order by 1` which is equivalent to order by nothing (random order)

Comment: @Tejash `order by 1 which is equivalent to order by nothing (random order)` .. This is not true. Numeric means it says column positions.

Comment: Another great reason to use explicit column names everywhere, and not ordinals!

Comment: @XING in terms of analytical function `order by 1` means nothing

Answer (score 5):

From ["About SQL Functions" - "Analytic Functions" - "order_by_clause"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm#i97469):

> **Restrictions on the ORDER BY Clause**
>
> The following restrictions apply to the `ORDER BY` clause:
>
> - (...) Position (`position`) and column aliases (`c_alias`) are also invalid. (...)

So no, a column position cannot be used in an `ORDER BY` of an `OVER` clause. It is therefore simply treated as if it were an integer literal. And since that literal is the same for all rows, there is no defined order.

Just use the column name instead. It's clearer anyway -- that applies also to the `ORDER BY` clause of a `SELECT` plus it doesn't break, if the order of columns is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a column name by position in the `ORDER BY` for an analytical (window) function.

`order by 1` means "*sort the result by the numeric value `1`*" so it sorts by a constant not the value of a column.

It's essentially the same as `order by 'foobar'` or `order by 99999`